# Extract data from a nested list, and convert to a tidy dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr

I have a data-reformatting problem that I need help with! I'm starting with a list-of-lists, and I'd like to turn it into a "tidy" dataframe that I can analyze further.

The structure of my list-of-lists looks like this:

```
str(wells, list.len = 3)  
    List of 96  
     $ A1 :List of 2  
      ..$ times : num [1:96] 0 900 1800 2700 3600 4500 5400 6300 7200 8100 ...  
      ..$ values: num [1:80] 0.0966 0.0928 0.0924 0.0931 0.0931 0.0939 0.0937 0.0938 0.0943 0.0949 ...  
      ..- attr(*, "name")= chr "A1"  
      ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "softermax.well"  
      ..- attr(*, "ID")= chr "1"  
      ..- attr(*, "row")= int 1  
      ..- attr(*, "col")= int 1  
     $ A2 :List of 2  
      ..$ times : num [1:96] 0 900 1800 2700 3600 4500 5400 6300 7200 8100 ...  
      ..$ values: num [1:80] 0.0945 0.0915 0.0912 0.0911 0.0913 0.0918 0.0921 0.0921 0.0923 0.0934 ...  
      ..- attr(*, "name")= chr "A2"  
      ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "softermax.well"  
      ..- attr(*, "ID")= chr "2"  
      ..- attr(*, "row")= int 1  
      ..- attr(*, "col")= int 2  
     $ A3 :List of 2  
      ..$ times : num [1:96] 0 900 1800 2700 3600 4500 5400 6300 7200 8100 ...  
      ..$ values: num [1:80] 0.0932 0.09 0.0898 0.0896 0.0898 0.0901 0.0903 0.0903 0.0911 0.0918 ...  
      ..- attr(*, "name")= chr "A3"  
      ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "softermax.well"  
      ..- attr(*, "ID")= chr "3"  
      ..- attr(*, "row")= int 1  
      ..- attr(*, "col")= int 3
```

I'd like the resulting data frame to have three columns, "Name", "Time" and "Value". "Name" should be the "name" attribute of each top-level list entry – there should be 80 rows in the final data frame for each value of "Name", where "Time" and "Value" are the first 80 entries from the "times" and "values" sub-lists. The 81st through 96th entries of "times" are NAs and need to be removed so that the "times" and "values" lists end up the same length.

I've been playing around with purr and map from tidyverse. I can extract some of the pieces I want, but haven't been able to figure out how to put them all together.

I can get the list of "Names" with:
`wellnames <- attributes(wells)`

I can use `purrr::map` to pull out the "times" and "values" for each of the sub-lists like so:
`x <- map(wells,`[`, c("times", "values"))`
but can't convert the resulting list of lists to a dataframe because "times" and "values" have different lengths (96 and 80, respectively, because of the extra NA values at the end of "times").

I can extract the desired values of "times" for the first sub-list:
`wells$A1$times[!is.na(wells$A1$times)]`
but can't figure out how to use purrr and a map function with is.na to extract the desired values of "times" for each of the 96 sub-lists.

If I could get the "times" without the NA values, then it should be fairly straightforward to convert the pieces into one or more dataframes and reshape/combine as needed using dplyr.

I know there has to be a tidyverse solution to this problem; I just haven't quite been able to figure out the syntax for dealing with the nesting and the NAs.

Here's the complete set of data for the first 3 sub-lists:

```
dput(wells[1:3])  
structure(list(A1 = structure(list(times = c(0, 900, 1800, 2700, 
3600, 4500, 5400, 6300, 7200, 8100, 9000, 9900, 10800, 11700, 
12600, 13500, 14400, 15300, 16200, 17100, 18000, 18900, 19800, 
20700, 21600, 22500, 23400, 24300, 25200, 26100, 27000, 27900, 
28800, 29700, 30600, 31500, 32400, 33300, 34200, 35100, 36000, 
36900, 37800, 38700, 39600, 40500, 41400, 42300, 43200, 44100, 
45000, 45900, 46800, 47700, 48600, 49500, 50400, 51300, 52200, 
53100, 54000, 54900, 55800, 56700, 57600, 58500, 59400, 60300, 
61200, 62100, 63000, 63900, 64800, 65700, 66600, 67500, 68400, 
69300, 70200, 71100, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), values = c(0.0966, 0.0928, 0.0924, 0.0931, 
0.0931, 0.0939, 0.0937, 0.0938, 0.0943, 0.0949, 0.0951, 0.096, 
0.0968, 0.098, 0.0991, 0.1004, 0.102, 0.1034, 0.1054, 0.1078, 
0.1103, 0.1132, 0.1161, 0.1196, 0.1234, 0.1279, 0.1329, 0.1381, 
0.144, 0.1505, 0.1574, 0.1648, 0.1732, 0.1819, 0.1912, 0.2018, 
0.2127, 0.232, 0.2436, 0.329, 0.4145, 0.3683, 0.4234, 0.5003, 
0.5291, 0.5463, 0.5472, 0.5664, 0.5649, 0.5618, 0.5487, 0.5494, 
0.5372, 0.5241, 0.4825, 0.5502, 0.544, 0.5415, 0.5319, 0.5234, 
0.5174, 0.5146, 0.5098, 0.4848, 0.3679, 0.3651, 0.3627, 0.3574, 
0.3686, 0.3577, 0.3689, 0.3528, 0.3584, 0.3573, 0.3471, 0.3571, 
0.3556, 0.3536, 0.3648, 0.3428)), .Names = c("times", "values"
), name = "A1", class = "softermax.well", ID = "1", row = 1L, col = 1L), 
    A2 = structure(list(times = c(0, 900, 1800, 2700, 3600, 4500, 
    5400, 6300, 7200, 8100, 9000, 9900, 10800, 11700, 12600, 
    13500, 14400, 15300, 16200, 17100, 18000, 18900, 19800, 20700, 
    21600, 22500, 23400, 24300, 25200, 26100, 27000, 27900, 28800, 
    29700, 30600, 31500, 32400, 33300, 34200, 35100, 36000, 36900, 
    37800, 38700, 39600, 40500, 41400, 42300, 43200, 44100, 45000, 
    45900, 46800, 47700, 48600, 49500, 50400, 51300, 52200, 53100, 
    54000, 54900, 55800, 56700, 57600, 58500, 59400, 60300, 61200, 
    62100, 63000, 63900, 64800, 65700, 66600, 67500, 68400, 69300, 
    70200, 71100, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), values = c(0.0945, 0.0915, 0.0912, 0.0911, 
    0.0913, 0.0918, 0.0921, 0.0921, 0.0923, 0.0934, 0.094, 0.0949, 
    0.0958, 0.0965, 0.098, 0.0994, 0.101, 0.1028, 0.1054, 0.1079, 
    0.1108, 0.1138, 0.1173, 0.1219, 0.1261, 0.1313, 0.1366, 0.1431, 
    0.1497, 0.1572, 0.1657, 0.1742, 0.1846, 0.195, 0.2066, 0.2203, 
    0.2329, 0.2507, 0.3472, 0.3383, 0.2988, 0.5052, 0.5218, 0.5425, 
    0.4873, 0.45, 0.532, 0.5555, 0.5582, 0.5819, 0.5856, 0.5698, 
    0.5713, 0.5837, 0.5698, 0.5674, 0.5612, 0.562, 0.5605, 0.5498, 
    0.5597, 0.556, 0.5412, 0.5382, 0.5329, 0.5367, 0.5417, 0.525, 
    0.5205, 0.532, 0.5119, 0.5255, 0.5138, 0.523, 0.5128, 0.5227, 
    0.5114, 0.5244, 0.5193, 0.5089)), .Names = c("times", "values"
    ), name = "A2", class = "softermax.well", ID = "2", row = 1L, col = 2L), 
    A3 = structure(list(times = c(0, 900, 1800, 2700, 3600, 4500, 
    5400, 6300, 7200, 8100, 9000, 9900, 10800, 11700, 12600, 
    13500, 14400, 15300, 16200, 17100, 18000, 18900, 19800, 20700, 
    21600, 22500, 23400, 24300, 25200, 26100, 27000, 27900, 28800, 
    29700, 30600, 31500, 32400, 33300, 34200, 35100, 36000, 36900, 
    37800, 38700, 39600, 40500, 41400, 42300, 43200, 44100, 45000, 
    45900, 46800, 47700, 48600, 49500, 50400, 51300, 52200, 53100, 
    54000, 54900, 55800, 56700, 57600, 58500, 59400, 60300, 61200, 
    62100, 63000, 63900, 64800, 65700, 66600, 67500, 68400, 69300, 
    70200, 71100, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), values = c(0.0932, 0.09, 0.0898, 0.0896, 
    0.0898, 0.0901, 0.0903, 0.0903, 0.0911, 0.0918, 0.0925, 0.0935, 
    0.0943, 0.0952, 0.0967, 0.0977, 0.1, 0.1018, 0.1041, 0.1067, 
    0.1092, 0.1156, 0.1151, 0.1193, 0.1238, 0.1284, 0.1334, 0.1402, 
    0.1464, 0.1533, 0.1614, 0.1698, 0.178, 0.1883, 0.1981, 0.2098, 
    0.2216, 0.2437, 0.3692, 0.4148, 0.4345, 0.4958, 0.5029, 0.4899, 
    0.5336, 0.5654, 0.547, 0.486, 0.5027, 0.5277, 0.4908, 0.5641, 
    0.5867, 0.5822, 0.5615, 0.5527, 0.5519, 0.5292, 0.3352, 0.3579, 
    0.3604, 0.3638, 0.366, 0.3787, 0.3737, 0.3645, 0.3674, 0.3794, 
    0.3589, 0.3981, 0.3361, 0.3508, 0.3217, 0.3196, 0.3176, 0.3645, 
    0.3532, 0.3528, 0.3267, 0.3473)), .Names = c("times", "values"
    ), name = "A3", class = "softermax.well", ID = "3", row = 1L, col = 3L)), .Names = c("A1", 
"A2", "A3"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `map_df` which automatically simplifies to a dataframe (tibble).

```
wells2 <- map_df(wells,
                 ~tibble(time = .$times[!is.na(.$times)],  #remove NAs to get lengths right
                         value = .$values),
                         .id = "name")                     #adds an id column
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr); library(purrr)

wells %>% 
  map(~tibble(time = na.omit(.x$times), value = na.omit(.x$values))) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "name")
```

For each list-element, make a `tibble`-dataframe with columns chosen from the `times` and `values` elements of the parent element.

---

More generically, if you want to apply a function to nested elements, you use `map_depth`.

```
wells %>% 
  map_depth(2, na.omit) %>% 
  map(as_tibble) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "name")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

enframe(na.omit(unlist(wells))) %>% 
  mutate(mrow = str_extract(name, '[[:digit:]]+$'),
         mvar = gsub('A|\\.|[[:digit:]]+', '', name),
         name = str_extract(name, '^A[[:digit:]]+')) %>% 
  spread(key = mvar, value = value) %>% 
  select(-mrow)

#> # A tibble: 240 x 3
#>    name  times values
#>    <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 A1        0 0.0966
#>  2 A1     8100 0.0949
#>  3 A1     9000 0.0951
#>  4 A1     9900 0.096 
#>  5 A1    10800 0.0968
#>  6 A1    11700 0.098 
#>  7 A1    12600 0.0991
#>  8 A1    13500 0.100 
#>  9 A1    14400 0.102 
#> 10 A1    15300 0.103 
#> # ... with 230 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `data.table`?

```
wells <- data.table::rbindlist(
  lapply(wells, function(x) lapply(x, `[`, 1:80)),
  idcol = 'name'
)
```